# is there any material for seleniumGrid + testNG+ hudson integration

Tags: selenium, hudson, testng, selenium-grid

I am using selenium RC + TestNG for my project. Also am using Selenium - Grid to run in multiple platforms. Now i want to intergrate my project into Hudson.. Can any one please help

Answer (score 0):

How are you currently running your tests?
Are you using anything to build your package e.g. Maven/Ant? 
Where are your source files stored? Local file system or in a repository?

Comment: My files are in local system which connected to VSS. For normal project I am using eclipse to run the testng.xml suite. For Grid i invoke remote machine as said in Docs using cmd and run testngGrid.xml suite file thru eclipse.... Now i want to integrate it into Hudson..i came to know that we require SVN + build file for hudson integration.. So i just want to know any good link for doing this

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know of any link which provides further details on putting this all together. I also havn't used VSS or ever ran used the TestNG XML suite files so i can't help much on that.

Comment: I can provide a brief explanation of how we have everything running together though:
We have a Maven project which includes the Selenium and TestNG libraries.
Our project consists of multiple test classes and a single "selenium manager" class which initiates a connection with the selenium grid.
The selenium manager uses TestNG annotation/properties which allow us to pass in parameters at run time for different environments e.g. -Dtest-environment=dev.example.com

Comment: This is checked into an SVN repository.
Our hudson jobs checkout this project from SVN and build/run it using maven.
We have a number of hudson jobs with different parameters passed in for testing different environments.
Our grid is started manually on a different machine to our hudson server. I know there are plugins for hudson to run your grid through the hudson ui, but we couldnt get this working at the time.